# Find every word using preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'd like to extract every word seperately from any phrase. I also need to match special characters, such as umlauts.

Currently, I use this:

```
preg_match_all('/\b([a-zA-ZäöüåÄÖÜÅ]*)\b/', $string, $matches);
```

However, this gives me redundant and empty matches. For example, "zu spät" returns

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => zu [1] => [2] => spät [3] => ) 
        [1] => Array ( [0] => zu [1] => [2] => spät [3] => ) )
```

What is the correct expression to match "any letter"? What can I do about the double and empty matches?

Comment: Perhaps you should try unicode equivalents of special characters. Not sure of its implementation though. A quick google may work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
preg_match_all('/\b\p{L}+\b/u', $string, $matches);
```

Where `\p{L}` matches any letters.

In your code sample you obtain the result "in double": the first is the whole pattern, the second is the capturing group. This is the reason why I have removed the capture group.
To avoid empty results, I have replaced the `*` quantifier (zero or more times) by the `+` quantifier (one or more times).